# Analyzing a two-dimensional dynamical system

Tags: plotting, calculus-and-analysis, nonlinear

In order to obtain the status of teacher in Switzerland I have to do some Maths exercises. One of them is all about *Mathematica*. My problem is that I have never used it, and it is not quite clear to me how to do it.

One of the exercise that should help me to prepare is this one

[image]

I know it may seems quite basic for some of you, but for me is a real challenge. Is there anyone who wants to show me how to do this kind of things with Mathematica?

Obviously I can understand that an explanation would require to much time, but also code could be enough, then I'll try to figure it out by myself.

Comment: While I kinda understand your worries, the question is about performing the mathematical analysis and _then_ implementing it in MMA. It's unlikely that anyone will want to do the whole work for you (I'm familiar with dynamical systems and chaos theory, and I know it's arduous - hence I'm not willing to do it). If you post all the parts that are to be implemented in MMA, you are more likely to receive help. Moreover, take a look [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/96004/plotting-a-bifurcation-diagram).

Comment: I can tell you that the exercise you quote is non-trivial even for an experienced Mathematica user who is also acquainted with non-linear dynamics. I am surprised to learn that someone who is new to Mathematica is expected to be able to tackle this level of problem.

Comment: [This](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/115653/transcritical-bifurcation-phase-portraits) is related, but not necessarily helpful.

Comment: You should provide the definition for "generic", I think, this being not commonly known and this being a site dedicated to *Mathematica* and not dynamical systems.