# Bifurcation diagram of a 2D system with a transcritical bifurcation

Tags: differential-equations

Consider the following system

$$\begin{align*}
\frac{dx}{dt}&=x(y-1)\\
\frac{dy}{dt}&=-y(x+a)+b
\end{align*}$$

At a value of $\dfrac{b}{a}=1$, there is a transcritical bifurcation. How can the bifurcation diagram be plotted?

There is an answer that shows it for a 1D system

[Transcritical Bifurcation phase portraits](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/115653/transcritical-bifurcation-phase-portraits)

but how can it be done for a 2D system?

Comment: What variables do you want on the x and y axes?

Comment: @ChrisK x (or y or sqrt(x^2+y^2) ) vs (b/a), to see where the two fixed points exchange stability

Comment: I suppose it's just a transcritical bifurcation, no pitchfork involved ?

Comment: @ChrisK, yes I've corrected the title. cheers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most minimal approach: just solve for equilibria and plot.  I'll set `a=1` and plot `x` vs `b`.

```
eq = Solve[{0 == x (y - 1), 0 == -y (x + a) + b}, {x, y}]
(* {{x -> -a + b, y -> 1}, {x -> 0, y -> b/a}} *)

a = 1;
Plot[Evaluate[x /. eq], {b, -0, 2}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Now, maybe you want to know which branch is stable.  We can do this analytically by finding eigenvalues of the Jacobian matrix, evaluated at the two equilibria.

```
j = D[{x (y - 1), -y (x + a) + b}, {{x, y}}]
(* {{-1 + y, x}, {-y, -1 - x}} *)

Eigenvalues[j /. eq[[1]]]
(* {-1, 1 - b} *)
```

This (blue) equilibrium is stable when `1-b<0`, equivalently when `b>1`.

```
Eigenvalues[j /. eq[[2]]]
(* {-1, -1 + b} *)
```

This (golden) equilibrium is stable when `-1+b<0`, equivalently when `b<1`.  Therefore there is an exchange of stability at the transcritical bifurcation point `b==1`.

Finally, maybe you want to style the equilibria in the bifurcation diagram to show their stability (say, solid=stable and dashed=unstable).  First, define the dominant eigenvalue

```
λ[bval_?NumericQ, pt_] := Max[Re[Eigenvalues[j /. pt] /. b -> bval]];
```

Then plot each equilibrium using `MeshFunctions` to indicate the stability.

```
Show[
  Plot[x /. eq[[1]], {b, 0, 2}, MeshStyle -> None,
    MeshFunctions -> {λ[#1, eq[[1]]] &}, Mesh -> {{0}}, 
    MeshShading -> {Directive[Black, Thick], Directive[Black, Dashed]}],
  Plot[x /. eq[[2]], {b, 0, 2}, MeshStyle -> None,
    MeshFunctions -> {λ[#1, eq[[2]]] &}, Mesh -> {{0}}, 
    MeshShading -> {Directive[Black, Thick], Directive[Black, Dashed]}]
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]