# Add empty point in an Epilog of a plot

Tags: plotting

I'm attempting to plot a phase plot for a 1d dynamical system, and mark the stable and unstable fixed point in empty and full point face color, but find it extremely difficult.

Can anyone pointout how to plot in the most simplified way empty and full circles in the same plot?

here is the code

```
    aa = 1.5;
f[x_] := a x - x^3;
Show[{Plot[f[x] /. a -> aa, {x, -2, 2}, 

   Ticks -> {{{-Sqrt[a] /. a -> aa, "-\!\(\*SqrtBox[\(a\)]\)"}, {0, 
       0}, {Sqrt[a] /. a -> aa, "\!\(\*SqrtBox[\(a\)]\)"}}, {{0, 
       0.1}}}, AxesLabel -> {"x", "f(x)"}, 
   Epilog -> {Black, PointSize@Large, Point[{0, 0}]}],
  VectorPlot[{a x - x^3 /. a -> aa, y}, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -0.1, 0.1}, 
   VectorPoints -> Table[{x, 0}, {x, -1.6, 1.6, 0.2}], 
   VectorScale -> Large]}]
```

Comment: Perhaps use something like `Inset["○", {1, 0}]` or `Inset["◦", {1, 0}]` for your empty points?

Comment: How about `Epilog -> {Annulus[{0, 0}, {0.45, 0.5}]}`

Comment: Related: [Transcritical Bifurcation phase portraits](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/115676/731)

Answer (score 4):

We can do what I did in my answer to the question [Transcritical Bifurcation phase portraits](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/115676/731), which was to use `Inset`:

```
unstable = {White, Disk[], Black, Thick, Circle[]};
Plot[
 1.5 x - x^3,
 {x, -2, 2},
 Epilog -> Inset[
   Graphics[unstable],
   {0, 0},
   {0, 0},
   Scaled[{0.05, 0.05}]
   ]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

In my other answer, I'm also showing how to draw stable and half-stable markers.

Comment: Also `unstable = {White, EdgeForm[Directive[Thick, Black]], Disk[]}`

Comment: My only problem with this solution is that the face color of the circle is not transparent

Comment: @jarhead It shouldn't be too difficult to figure out how to change that, just look at the graphics directive `{White, Disk[], Black, Thick, Circle[]}` and take a guess at what you need to do in order to remove the white.

Comment: @C.E, add it to your answer and I'll accept